# change default texts in react-data-table-component

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

Is it possible to change the default texts in react data table component? For example when there are no data available, it says "There are no records to display" but i need to change the text based on the language the user have selected. Is it possible to change default texts and font?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `noDataComponent` attribute in your DataTable component

```js
<DataTable
    columns={columns}
    noDataComponent="Your Text Here" //or your component
    data={data}          
    pagination
/>
```